# Google Chrome keeps launching old version after update

Tags: 14.04, updates, google-chrome, launcher, update-manager

I had Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) installed on a recently Upgraded  Ubuntu 14.04 (from 12.04), and updated Chrome using:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

The install seems to have completed fine.
Then I launched Chrome trying both the old Chrome icon I had on the launcher and using `google-chrome` and `google-chrome-stable` from terminal.

All 3 keel launching the old version, at least according to the the version in the About Google Chrome tab.

I then tried to uninstall and re-install using combinations of:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

OR

Install from Software Center.

I still keep getting the darn version 41.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me and I resolved it with

```
killall chrome
```

[Others have suggested](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/l9vdrFb4TiI/aHtKe3e3m-EJ) that a reboot solves the problem.

Apparently there is some residual of the old version still running, despite the uninstall.

Comment: This worked for me. Looks like the old chrome session was still running. Kill all or reboot should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google has stopped supporting 12.04 and no matter how hard you try, you will never see an update.

You have to uninstall **Chrome** completely so that it removes Google's update server from your system and download the new **google-chrome** from google.  After you install the new one, a server with new keys will be added to your system and updates will start appearing again.

Comment: How do I uninstall Chrome "completely"?

Comment: You have done it already.  Use the same command. `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`.  Check the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder and make sure both **google-chrome.list** and **google-chrome.list.save** are gone.  If not, delete them manually.  After that, execute `sudo apt-get update` to notify the system about the server removal.

Comment: I've done all of that, yet I continue to launch version 41 even though it has installed version 52.

Comment: It seems the old version is not actually uninstalled.  Don't use apt-get for the new installation.  Download the .deb manually.

Comment: I've done that from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html.
 Still same issue.

Comment: ic.  Let's see if somebody else can help you better then.  :-)

Comment: This seemed to have solved it:
rm -rf /home/username/.config/google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04(64-bit) was stuck on chrome version 48 something...

I did these steps to update chrome successfully.

1. Remove chrome

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Restart your system
3. Download and install latest .deb file from the following URL
   https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html